# Fitting two textboxes of a second row under one text box of the first row

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have written this part to achieve this UI:

```
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right">@Html.Label("Email", new {@class = "control-label"})</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.TextBox("AdminEmail", null, new {@style = "width:100%;padding-right:30px;"})
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback" style="right: 10px; line-height: 27px;"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div>
                    @Html.CheckBox("ShowAdminPhone", new {@class = "checkbox-inline"})
                    @Html.Label("Show Admin phone", new {@class = "control-label"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Now under this Label and TextBox I want to have a Phone and Ext labels and textboxes aligned, so I added this:

```
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right">@Html.Label("Phone", new {@class = "control-label"})</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.TextBox("AdminPhone")
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1 text-right">@Html.Label("Ext", new { @class = "control-label" })</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.TextBox("AdminExt")
            </div>
        </div>
```

But now it is looking like this, notice that Label for Ext is way far and Textbox for Ext is also way off, they should all fit under the Email textbox .
What is it I am doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using span classes for your labels?

Use CSS to style your span classes' margin/padding.
You can customize the length of columns to your liking: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

EDIT:

```
        <div class="row form-group">
         <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <span class="form-label">@Html.Label("Email", new {@class = "control-label"})</span>
          <span class="form-textbox">
            @Html.TextBox("AdminEmail", null, new {@style = "width:100%;padding-right:30px;"})
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback" style="right: 10px; line-height: 27px;"></span></span>
         </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <span class="form-checkbox">
                @Html.CheckBox("ShowAdminPhone", new {@class = "checkbox-inline"})</span>
             <span class="form-label>   @Html.Label("Show Admin phone", new {@class = "control-label"})</span>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <span class="form-label">@Html.Label("Phone", new {@class = "control-label"})</span>
          <span class="form-textbox">
            @Html.TextBox("AdminPhone")
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <span class="form-label">@Html.Label("Ext", new { @class = "control-label" })</span>
        <span class="form-textbox">
            @Html.TextBox("AdminExt")
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am really new to all front-end dev stuff, can you please explain more what you have in mind? thanks.